# The BETWEEN operator cannot be used with a subquery; however, the BETWEEN operator can be used within the subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am unable to understand following rule of subquery..can anyone please help me in understanding this with example if possible...

```
"The BETWEEN operator cannot be used with a subquery; however, the BETWEEN operator can be used within the subquery"
```

[image]

Comment: You can't do `... between (select...) and ...`, but you can do `... (select ... where col between ...)`

Answer (score 0):

These are two different statements :

A) **The BETWEEN operator cannot be used with a subquery**

This example is not allowed:

```
select * from MY_TABLE where CODE between (select INI_COD from CONFIG) and 999
```

A subquery cannot be used as an operand of the BETWEEN operator

B) **The BETWEEN operator can be used within a subquery**

This example is allowed :

```
select CODE, (select top 1 NAME from NAMES where ID between CODE and 999)
from MY_TABLE
```

The BETWEEN operator can be used within your subqueries

Comment: Hi Marc...Thanks for your reply..Me too thought the same but both the queries are executing properly. please see this image  http://ingenius.in/subquery.jpg

Comment: Probably this bit of documentation is outdated and now both uses are allowed.